# Why is Couchdb not compressing my SVG attachments with gzip?

Tags: database, http, ubuntu, compression, couchdb

i have a problem with the compression of attachments in Apache **Couchdb 1.2.0** running on **Ubuntu 12.04 LTS**.

I've added a Content-Type **image/svg+xml** in the Futon Configuration Section.

attachments | compressible_types | text/*, application/javascript, application/json, application/xml, **image/svg+xml**

The local.ini was correctly updated. After i've restarted the couchdb, i uploaded a svg-file as attachment. I call it, the Request-Header seems to be ok (Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate), but he Response-Header shows no encoding-section (gzip). The filesize looks not compressed.

I couldn't find a solution for this problem around the web. Do you have any solutions to solve this problem?

Thx

Comment: the compression works correctly for text/*, application/javascript, application/json and application/xml

Comment: If you can't find a solution, you could try manually gzipping the SVG files through a script (php, python etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is case not handled in CouchDB properly. A workaround is to declare the mime-type as `image/svg\+xml`.

I opened a bug on the CouchDB Issue tracker: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-1497

Comment: Thanks a lot Jan. The workaround with mime-type image/svg\\\+xml don't works for me, but with image/svg\+xml it works correctly. I've tried it on couchdb 1.0.1 for now.

Comment: fair enough :) editing my original reply. this should also work in 1.2.0. I hope we get that fixed for 1.2.1